# Retrieve list of all the elements on a page

Tags: asp.net-core, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I clearly don't understand how locators work.
How do I retrieve a list of all the elements on a page where the name matches a pattern?

```
    // this was translated from javascript
    public async Task<List<string>> ListOfItems(IPage page, string pattern) {
        await page.WaitForSelectorAsync('.' + pattern);
        var itemlists = await page.$$(pattern); // this doesn't translate

        List<string> allitems = new List<string>();

        foreach (var itemlist in itemlists) {
            allitems.Add(await itemlist.innerText());
        }
        return allitems;
    }
```

My immediate use case is a page that should have a list of items displayed from the database. If there are 5 items in the database, there should be 5 items in the list. I thought this might be a generally useful routine, but I don't have any other specific use cases yet.

---update---
This looks promising.
Tries to use partial CSS selectors, so I can select on name, class, or id.
On the downside, it doesn't use the playwright API.
But gives 'Unexpected token "^=" while parsing selector "id^=note"'

```
    Assert.AreEqual(5, (await ListOfItems(page, "id^=note")).Count());

    public async Task<List<string>> ListOfItems(IPage page, string pattern) {
        var locator = page.Locator(pattern);
        var itemlist = await locator.AllAsync(); //fails here
        List<string> allitems = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in itemlist) {
            // Get the element handle for the item
            var element = await item.ElementHandleAsync();
            // Get the inner text for the element
            var text = await element.InnerTextAsync();
            allitems.Add(text);
        }
        return allitems;
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this method? What's `pattern`? If it's a partial CSS selector, then the calls are different--on the `WaitForSelectorAsync` call, you've prepended a `.` which denotes a class, while on the `.$$` call, you've omitted the period, which would break the selector. Generally, it's better to use the [locator API](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/locators), and when asking a question, it's good to provide full context for what you're really trying to accomplish, so a better way can be provided. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I was picturing more of a regex, but partial CSS selectors look like exactly what I need. Context added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [] around id^=note. The syntax of the CSS selecto should be [attribute^=value]. So, the correct CSS selector is

```
[id^="note"]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how CSS selector should look like in this case as `[attribute^=value]`

```
'*[id^="note"]'
```

' * '  simply means , the element type(tag) can be of any kind like div or button or anything however it must have the unique property called "id" having the value as "note" to start with.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors

Comment: This works, but what is the * for? I get the same results with or without.

Comment: @BWhite * means select all the elements. It is optional, so you get same results with or without *.  You can read more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#the_universal_selector